# How / When is IAP information added to iOS app receipts?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store, receipt-validation

**Short Version:**

My freemium iOS app sends the app receipt to my server for validation and to check wether a users is eligible for subscription introductory offers. I noticed that there are a lot of receipts with no IAPs inside. This would mean that many users have been using the free trial version for years, which is quite unlikely.

**So when is IAP informatioin added to the receipts?**

---

**Long Version:**

My app has been offered in the iOS App Store for several years using a **Freemium Model**: User can download the app for free and test it for an unlimited time with limited features. A **non-consumable** in-app purchase can than be uses to remove these feature limits.

In theory users can use the app indefinitely without any purchase just using the test feature set. However, the due to the limitations this is highly unlikely.

Recently I have updated the app to offer subscription. To check if users are eligible for introductory offers the app receipt is send to my server for validation.

I noticed that there are a lot of receipts with no IAPs inside. Even for receipts with `original_app_version`s which are several years old. This would mean that many users have been using the free trial version for years, which is quite unlikely (due to the very limited feature set).

**So when is IAP informatioin added to the receipts?**

The new app version send the receipt to my server on the first start. There are three possible cases:

1. The app was never used before and this is the first installation of the app ever.

   - `original_app_version` == current version
   - Of course on the first start there are no IAPs, so nothing unusual in this
2. This an updated of an earlier version which was installed before

   - `original_app_version` < current version
   - The app / App Store hat plenty of time to include possible IAPs in the receipt
3. An earlier version of the app was used but than uninstalled. Now the current version has been re-installed

   - `original_app_version` < current version
   - Since has just been installed it might be possible that the IAPs are not included in the receipt yet?case.

So, only the 2. and 3. case interesting here. Why should previous **non-consumable** IAPs be stored in the 2. case since the app has been installed and running for a long time?

On the other hand it quite unlikely that thousands of previous users have now re-installed my app and thus resulted in case 3. Even if this really the case, is there anything the app can do to manually trigger the store to add previous IAPs to the receipts? **Or does the user have to restore previous purchases first?**

---

**EDIT:**

As far as I understand the Appel docs it does not really matter what information is stored in the receipt which can be found on the devices. When I upload this receipt to my server it acts like an token when being send to Apple for validation.

Apple than responds with the **latest** receipt information available (if the receipt/token was valid) in clear text.

Thus it shouldn't really matter how long the app was installed on the device or wether it was a new install or a re-install: Apple provides the latest information available. Thus if there ever was an IAP it should be included in the returned information. **Right?**

But this would mean that there are **thousands** of users which have been using a very, very, very limited trial version over years which seems very, very, very unlikely...

**Is there any other explanation?**